# Add an onclick event on a marker Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

Although somehow, there are several questions related to my question, this is why my question is different. Using Phonegap, I have an `index.html` and `gmap.html`. On my `index.html`, my href contains parameters :

example: `gmap.html?&name=Agustina%20Apartments&lat=14.625486&lng=121.02333099999998`

I was able to parse the parameters and put a marker on the map. However, I want to assign an onclick on the marker. I have this code:

`google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', callNumber('84'));`

Now, what I am trying to do is when the user clicks on the marker, the accompanied contact_number will be opened on the phones's dialer so the user can call the establishment. I have a code that setups a marker using the coordinates from the url. I tried to put it inside my `onSuccess` callback of my `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` method with timeout of 5 seconds. What happens is every 5 seconds, the dialer will appear with the phone number (because of the timeout). However, when I click on the marker, nothing happens. I tried to put it in my `initialize()` function, but it showed dialer before showing the map, and the marker not being able to detect click events.

Here is a more detailed code:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.6333, 121.0333)
   };


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

  var estabCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
  var estabMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: estabCenter
  });
  var estabCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
    center: estabCenter
  });

  estabCircle.setRadius(100);

  google.maps.event.addListener(estabMarker, 'click', callNumber('84'));
// Try HTML5 geolocation
if(navigator.geolocation) {
  mapAutoUpdate();
  } else {
  // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function callNumber(number){
    window.open('tel:'+number+'', '_system');
}
```

Thank you for those who will help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply a function as callback, not a function-call(except the call returns another function):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(estabMarker, 'click', function(){callNumber('84');});
```

Comment: `Supply a function as callback, not a function-call(except the call returns another function)` One sentence is enough. Amazing. Thank you Sir.

Comment: May I ask why having a function call is not working while giving it a `function` does?

Comment: A function will be executed when the event has been triggered, but a function-call will be executed immmediately(when the browser evaluates the particular line/statement)